# Input using Scanner Class

Tags: java

I am a new java programmer, In my below code when am trying to enter the employee name like john smith, only john is getting printed in output. 
And if I put

```
System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");   
String employeeName = s.next();
```

**above**

```
System.out.print("Enter SEX: ");       
char SEX = s.next().charAt(0);
```

this piece of code in output is not asking for my employeename value. and directly printing the remaining values.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
**package cs480;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CS480D1_Richa_2_Week2 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);  
     System.out.print("Ente Employee ID: ");
     int employeeId = s.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Ente SEX: ");       
     char SEX = s.next().charAt(0);
     System.out.print("Ente Employee Name: ");
     String employeeName = s.next();
     System.out.println("Employee ID is " +employeeId);
     System.out.println("Employee Name is " +employeeName);
     System.out.println("Employee gender is " +SEX);
    }        

}**
```

Comment: Check the `Related` section on the right. You will get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ente Employee ID: ");
    int employeeId = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ente SEX: ");
    char SEX = s.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Ente Employee Name: ");
    String employeeName = s.nextLine();
    employeeName = s.nextLine();// Try to add this line of code
    System.out.println("Employee ID is " + employeeId);
    System.out.println("Employee Name is " + employeeName);
    System.out.println("Employee gender is " + SEX);

}
```

Comment: Hi Erika, Thank you now it is working as expected. When I was using just String employeeName = s.nextLine(); it was not working. Why did you add that line?

Comment: That means char SEX = s.next().charAt(0); command only reads the char value. So after that line, we need to read s.nextLine(); to perform '\n' Enter key. After that employeeName = s.nextLine(); this code read the user input of employeeName. so you can also write to clear the code like this : s.nextLine(); String employeeName = s.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code

**String employeeName = scanner.nextLine();**

instead

**String employeeName = scanner.next();**

next() can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, next() places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

nextLine() reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, nextLine() positions the cursor in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use

```
scanner.nextLine()
```

or override delimiter to use next()

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` uses a white-space delimiter(takes the element before white-space).

So either use

```
Scanner.nextLine()
```

or reset the delimiter using

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*"your delimiter"\\s*");
```